# MSI Installer fails during uninstall when serivce was already removed

Tags: windows-services, windows-installer

I've an Installer with some custom actions & the designer fancy to install a windows service.

From times to times, when I made a mistake in my custom actions (or in the MSI configuration) the upgrade process may fail. Solution is to uninstall the Application and do a fresh installation.

But sometimes I'm ending in the situation, where I can't uninstall the Application because the "custom actions" for the service claims, that the service is not registered in the system. OK, maybe, no problem. I'm uninstalling the App. The problem: my app don't get uninstalled. It remains. I have to manually add the service to the registry again and restart the uninstall process.

Question: What do I have to configure/develop/program/etc. to tell the service (un)installer not to fail during uninstall when the service is already removed.

BTW: My custom actions do *NOTHING* during uninstallation. Only during installation/upgrade, I'm asking the user for some configuration and do some custom config stuff - only related to my app. Not related to the service.

EDIT: forgot to mention: VS 2008, default installer project, no fancy stuff, target machine is Windows XP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's one of the many reasons I say not to use VDPROJ and InstallUtil custom actions.    You need to put a try catch block in your uninstall custom action and handle that scenario.

Hopefully you are testing on a VM and can just revert but in case this is your dev box  use the Windows SC command to recreate the service so you can get the uninstall to work for now.

If you really want to do this right, you want to do something like this:

[Augmenting InstallShield using Windows Installer XML - Windows Services](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows_19.html)

The same concept applies you'll just be adding the WiX merge module to your VDPROJ installer.

Comment: Yeah - I'm willing to switch to another installer, but *insert all known excused here*. My problem is, I don't see the place where I can put a try catch. I'm adding the installer components with this.Installers.AddRange(...). This code was created by the fancy desinger for setup/installer projects. Service is recreated by a registry script :-)

Comment: Sorry, that is all out of process, fragile crap.  It's one of the reasons Microsoft is deprecating those project types and offering InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition for free instead.   If you switch to IS or WiX I can help you but I don't provide help when dealing with antipatterns.

Comment: OK, I'll give InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition a chance. Thanks! Arthur